# I am getting error in web scraping using python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am getting following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "ex1.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(soup.prettify())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encodereturn
    codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position35013: character maps to <undefined>
```

My source code is as below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=coffee&geo_location_terms=Los+Angeles%2C+CA'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 0):

changing to this works in mine

```
html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.prettify()
```

Comment: No, still this is not working for me. I want to get all the html contents not just text.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on Windows? Cause the problem is due to the encoding of your html contents.

I think this may work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=coffee&geo_location_terms=Los+Angeles%2C+CA'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify().encode('UTF-8'))
```

Passing arguments for encoding on `prettify()` should work too. Like this:

```
soup.prettify(encoding='utf-8')
```